# SIR epidemic model with vital dynamics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, mathematical-modeling

I am reading the Wikipedia article on the [SIR model with vital dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology#The_SIR_model_with_vital_dynamics_and_constant_population).
I am wondering about the birth and death rate. The birth rate seems to be constant, ie, it seems like the population in all 3 compartments reproduce, and overall, newborns are added to the S compartment at a constant rate. It sounds reasonable.

Based on the definition of R compartment, it seems like dead people are also added in this section. I quote

> R for the number of removed (and immune) or deceased individuals.

What I am wondering is shouldn't the last equation with R be?
$$ \frac{dR}{dt} =  \gamma I + \mu S + \mu I $$
The dead people from S and I should get added to R compartment. This further raises another doubt, if compartment R is indeed filled by dead people as well, then my justification of constant birth rate fails. My logic was that the birth rate would be proportional to $ \propto (S + I + R)=N $
so it is a constant. However, now dead people can't reproduce and hence R compartment can't reproduce at a rate proportional to $R$. It would be much lower due to dead people.

Comment: Your specific link is to "The SIR model with vital dynamics and constant population" and since people in the $R$ compartment later die at the same rate as other compartments, it seems to suggest either that this disease does not actually kill people, or that they are only counted as removed from the model if they would have died for some other reason, and similarly for the other compartments - somebody susceptible but not infected can die immediately in this model but not from this disease

Comment: @Henry Okay, there seem to be some unreasonable assumptions there in the model. So, if I understood correctly, birthrate being constant is also an assumption with no immediate justification?

Comment: Birthrate and deathrate are constant and equal to each other as part of  *vital dynamics and constant population*

Comment: Ahh.. now I see it. Thanks!